# What is the relationship between apache and a SVN repository on a Windows Box?

Tags: windows, svn

I am researching something but apache seems to come up everywhere I look.

What role does apache play when setting up a SVN Server on a Windows Box?
As I just need the above, I don't need any apache on my new windows box at work as all websites are hosted externally. I jus need a code repository but on a Windows box as at my new work place no one here has any unix skills so that would overkill if I set it up like that. So it has to be on a Windows Box.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Apache serves as the intermediary between the repo itself and the users, typically using apache's [mod_dav_svn](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.mod_dav_svn.conf.html).

Comment: ok, can I get away with no using it then?

Comment: svnserve is a bundled product with Subversion and does provide a different alternative for accessing Subversion repositories.  However, it does not provide the robustness that Apache can offer as well as it can be a pain in the arse with firewalls.  If managing an Apache instance for Subversion feels daunting, get the Subversion Edge binaries from CollabNet.  They'll take the mystery of configuring and managing Apache away for Subversion.

Comment: Please update the URL you are referencing to a newer version or even the nightly version of the Subversion book.  Google has a nasty habit of pulling 5+ year old documentation about Subversion for some reason.

Comment: Ahh, my bad. Thanks for the heads up, jgifford25, and for the fix Zoredache.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I will investigate Subversion Edge.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using the repository locally and there are no remote users you can access it via the file protocol:

```
cd \repo
svnadmin create .
cd \sandbox
svn co file:///repo
```